# Optimized Dex Compiling

Tags: basic4android

Version 1.70 is acting strange.  The delay is taking longer.  Few days back it would take 20-26 seconds and then for every 5 compiling i would get 120 seconds.  Now, it is taking 120 seconds on every compiling.  I don't mind the wait.  Maybe it has to do with more coding I recently added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it is related to v1.70, as there were no changes in this version related to the compilation process. Does it say: Optimized dexer or Standard dexer in the compilation window?

Comment: Convert byte code - optimized dex.      71.70
 Standard dexer.
Now it is 71.  Yesterday, was 120 all day.

Comment: Yesterday, it was @ 120.  I am having hard time replying the results in proper format. Here are the results for today.                                                              
Convert byte code - optimized dex.      75.41 Standard dexer.

Comment: Yesterday, it was @ 120.  Here are the results for today.                                                                  Compiling code.                         0.41
Generating R file.                      0.00
Compiling generated Java code.          2.08
Convert byte code - optimized dex.      75.41
 Standard dexer.
Packaging files.                        1.23
Signing package file (debug key).       0.65
ZipAlign file.                          0.03
Installing file to device.              0.06

Comment: How large is your project? Try cleaning your project - Tools - Clean project. Also make sure that no unneeded libraries are referenced.

Comment: 2700 lines of codes.  No files to clean as per msg.  I am using Phone, Dialag, RandomFile, and Serial.  No biggie.  I can wait minute or two.

Comment: 2700 lines of code should usually compile in a few seconds. You should try Tools - Clean project, not clean files. It is also possible that your computer is low on resources.

Comment: You can also disable the debugger (Project - Attach debugger). It will make compilation faster.

Comment: Thanks Erel!  I sometimes overlook things.  Clean Project did the job.  Now it is at Convert byte code - optimized dex.      13.25  Not Bad with Debugger on.  I can live with that :)